# When I say Hello guys

Tags: informal-language

When I say "hello guys" in an online forum, Is it considered that I'm talking to some men? Or it's for every human beings? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all I have to say that the word "guy" is used in informal English only and although it means man or boy, it is normally used for people of either sex, and this happens mainly in the USA, not so much in Britain.